# Inflated Views inside a ListView are not visible

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create a inflated dialog which contains dynamic amount of items.
These Items I inflate aswell.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int anzJobViews = getArguments().getInt("param");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_job_chooser, container, false);
    //getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_chooser_listview);

    for (int i = 0; i < anzJobViews; i++) {
        listview.addFooterView( new JobItemView(context));
        Log.i("JobChooser","Item added");
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

The View (Contains some simple TextViews)

```
private void init() {

    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.job_item_view, this);

}
```

When showing the dialog I see Nothing. 
The xml layout for the dialog.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_selected"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/washedOutGreen">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_chooser_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Items a want to add to the List.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue_focused">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_jobname_area"
        android:text="defaultName"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_jobvalue_area"
        android:text="0 /h"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_jobname_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use an adapter to populate your listview? An example from here: http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

```
    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(currentListData.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.tvDesc.setText(currentListData.getDescription());
        mViewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(currentListData.getImgResId());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
        ImageView ivIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDesc = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            ivIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you are in a pre kitkat enviroment, you can only use addFooterView before setting the adapter.

> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

Comment: You could also check the Android Adapter tutorials: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews - Hope it helps :)

Comment: taught i could just add items the list without the adapter. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `getView` function to setup your listview

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list)  {
        View element;
        if (convertView == null) {
         element = View.inflate(context, R.layout.items, null);
        }
        else {
            element = convertView;
        }
//setup here something
//e.g.
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("myText");
    return element;
    }
```